# TypeError: Operator == not compatible with types contract IERC20 and address

Tags: solidity

My goal is to compare my `IERC20` contract with my `address repaymentCurrency` in a require statement:

`require(currency == listing.loanDetails.repaymentCurrency, "Error");`

However, I keep getting the following error:

`TypeError: Operator == not compatible with types contract IERC20 and address`

Any ideas about what's going on?

Comment: what are currency and listing.loanDetails.repaymentCurrency? are you comparing addresses?#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently allowed by the language. You can only compare an address with an address or a contract with a contract (which includes interfaces since they're considered a kind of a contract).

Either convert the interface to the `address` type:

```solidity
require(address(currency) == listing.loanDetails.repaymentCurrency, "Error");
```

or the address to an interface:

```solidity
require(currency == IERC20(listing.loanDetails.repaymentCurrency), "Error");
```

but I'd reccommend the former since comparing contract instances will likely be disallowed in the future ([#11700](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/11700)).